# Curl request with array values as input for query (GET) params

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, curl

I have output from an array I would like to use as input in a PHP Curl request.  Do I store them as another array and loop through the array with the Curl request?

Here is the output from the array:

```
foreach ($threadsarray['threads'] as $thread) {   
    print $thread['id']."<br />";
}
```

These are values I would like to use as input for Curl (obviously these values are different every time depending on the output for each loop above):

```
178369845
291476958
224408290
270960091
270715888
270513013
229639500
229630641
215503057
214314923
```

I want to execute a curl request for each of those thread id's...
Here is how I am building the Curl request:

```
$url2 = 'https://api.website.com/endpoint';

    $data2 = array (
        'specialkey' => '123abcd789xyz',
        'anotherparam' => 'Brown',
        'locale' => 'en-US',
        'thread_id' => array (
                       $thread['id']
                       )
        );

        //build the query string because this is a get request
        $params2 = '';
        foreach($data2 as $key2=>$value2)
                $params2 .= $key2.'='.$value2.'&';

        $params2 = trim($params2, '&');


        // Excecute the curl request
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url2.'?'.$params2 );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 'false');
        $mycurlresult = curl_exec($ch);
echo '<pre>';
$resultarray = json_decode($mycurlrequest, TRUE);
print_r($resultarray);
echo '</pre>';
        if (FALSE === $mycurlrequest)
            throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch));
```

I can't seem to build the request string correctly...what am I missing?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: I'm getting Array to string conversion on the following line:$params2 .= $key2.'='.$value2.'&';

Comment: Do you know about [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)?

Comment: You're getting that array to string conversion because one of the `$value2`s in `$data2` is an array.

Comment: Maybe you just want `$thread['id']` instead of `array($thread['id'])`?

Comment: Correct.  I have an array of parameters within another array of parameters.  I need to loop through each of those, build the curl request and perform the curl request, return data, insert data into database.  But I can't even seem to build the query string correctly because of the array within the array.

Comment: I see. Just to be clear - the API doesn't accept an array of IDs, so you need to make multiple requests, one for each ID?

Comment: Correct.  The API does not accept an array of ID's, so there needs to be multiple requests.  The number of requests depends on how many thread ID's are returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't really test this, but I'd suggest something like this. First, set up your curl, and create an array with an empty placeholder for thread_id.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 'false');

$url2 = 'https://api.website.com/endpoint';
$data2 = array(
    'specialkey' => '123abcd789xyz',
    'anotherparam' => 'Brown',
    'locale' => 'en-US',
    'thread_id' => ''
);
```

Then loop over your array. For each item, replace the `thread_id` key in the `$data2` parameters array with that item's id, build the query using `http_build_query` and execute the request.

```
foreach ($threadsarray['threads'] as $thread) {
    $data2['thread_id'] = $thread['id'];                  // add the current id
    $params2 = http_build_query($data2);                  // build the new query
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url2.'?'.$params2 );
    $mycurlresult = curl_exec($ch);
    echo '<pre>';
    $resultarray = json_decode($mycurlrequest, TRUE);
    print_r($resultarray);
    echo '</pre>';
    if (FALSE === $mycurlrequest)
        throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch));
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir.  You nailed it.  Much appreciated!!

Comment: Instead of this foreach loop creating 10 different arrays as output, is there a way to get the output into 1 array?  Or is there an easy way to step through each of the 10 arrays after the foreach completes?

Comment: Sure, just append to `$resultarray` instead of overwriting it. `$resultarray[] = json_decode($mycurlrequest, TRUE);`.

Comment: Ah, yes.  But it's still printing each array as it's appending.  I'm after the last array (the total combined array).  Is there a way to only print that one?

Comment: Yep, just move your print to after the loop instead of inside it.

Comment: Thank you again for all your help.  I'm obviously just starting out with php.